# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: >Encountered "FROM"

Tags: sql, jpa, javadb

I'm building a currency converter application using JavaEE. The Web-based client enters an amount and the currencies (for ex. 'USD' and 'EUR').

I'm not an expert in SQL, when I run and test the webpage I receive the following error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: >Encountered "FROM" at line 1, column 12. Error Code: 30000 Call: SELECT >ID, FROM, RATE, TO, VALUE FROM RATE WHERE ((FROM = ?) AND (TO = ?)) bind >=> [2 parameters bound] Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Rate >sql="SELECT ID, FROM, RATE, TO, VALUE FROM RATE WHERE ((FROM = ?) AND (TO >= ?))")

I used entity manager method `createQuery` that gets the these values and try to find the currencies conversion rate:

```
public double convertTo(double value, String from, String to) {
    TypedQuery<Rate> query = em.createQuery(""
            + "SELECT c FROM Rate c WHERE c.from = :from AND c.to = :to", Rate.class);

    query.setParameter("to", to);
    query.setParameter("from", from);

    Rate result = query.getSingleResult();

    if (result == null) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("Can't find rate");
    }

    return value * result.getValue();
}
```

I'm trying to change the query but it's not working either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

escape `from` column because it is keyword or rename it.

try double quotes "from" or [from]

Comment: Yes, it was the keyword, thanks @Peter_Saly. The problem now is that `query.getSingleResult();` doesn't find the row in my database that matches the from and to currencies. it gives me the exception: "getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities." My table has 4 col: id, fromcurrency, tocurrency, rate. I will try to see this issue now. :(

Comment: I recomend to use rates to reference currency. Reference currency could be  euro. With referrence currency you dont need maintain all combinations. Load all rates. Calculation will be to euro then to destination currency. No precision loss.